# akka http websocket client not working with ripple websocket

Tags: scala, akka-http

I'm new to Akka http. Im using the latest stable request version 2.4.7 .
Im trying to connect to a websocket and I was able to do so. The problem is when I use it using "wss://s1.ripple.com" the connection closes after the handshake.

```
val incoming: Sink[Message, Future[Done]] =
  Sink.foreach[Message] {
    case message: TextMessage.Strict =>
      println(message.text)
    case message:TextMessage.Streamed =>
      println(message)
    case message => println

  }

val outgoing = Source.single(TextMessage("""{"command" : "fee"}"""))

  val webSocketFlow = Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("wss://echo.websocket.org"))


  val (upgradeResponse, closed) = outgoing
    .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right)
    .toMat(incoming)(Keep.both) 
    .run()

  val connected = upgradeResponse.flatMap { upgrade =>
    if (upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.OK || upgrade.response.status == StatusCodes.SwitchingProtocols) {
      Future.successful(Done)
    } else {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"Connection failed: ${upgrade.response.status}")
    }
  }

  connected.onComplete(r => println(s"camote ${r} ${upgradeResponse}"))
  closed.foreach(_ => println("closed"))
```

/==================================================Update===
I can now get message from the server. seems like adding Source.empty did the trick . But the problem now is that i cant disconnect from the server ... Source.empty keeps the connection alive until timeout. Can I manually close to connection to the server from the client?

```
val source=Source.single(TextMessage.Strict(<JsStringMessage>)).concatMat(Source.maybe)(Keep.left)

  val source =
      Http().webSocketClientFlow(WebSocketRequest("<wss url>"))

  val (done,data)= handshaker
      .viaMat(webSocketFlow)(Keep.right)
      .toMat(Sink.last)(Keep.both) 
      .run()

    val resuldata:Future[String] = data.map{
      case message:TextMessage.Strict => message.text
      case message =>"""{"status" : "failed"}"""
    }
    resuldata
```